# Google Calendar One-Way Sync

Tags: sync, android, google-calendar, calendar.app, google-sync

I use Google Calendar and wish to sync it with my Android phone. Events I schedule from my PC always show up on my phone after sync, but events I schedule on my phone never show up on my on my PC when I log on to Google Calendar. The Sync function only seems to work one-way from computer to phone, but not from phone to computer.

Are there any work arounds for this?

Comment: On your PC, which program are you scheduling your appointments in? How are you sync'ing the calendar/phone exactly?

Comment: I just access Google calendar through my web browser, then I sync onto my phone. I am not using Outlook or any other software at the moment. But things I enter on my phone while out and about never make it back to my desktop Google Calendar.

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/calendar/al59SHBIkxs/TVnRLA3VXQEJ

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an ongoing issue with Google sync.  IIRC there are some support tickets and help requests, and the upstart is that sync seems to work reliably in one direction only.

I really really wanted to find a way to make Google Tasks work, and in the end, I subscribed to Remember the Milk.  It does sync.  It has all the features you would want, and has a free option so you can get acquainted.  I have been on the paid version for two years now.

The repeat task, and schedule task features make up for the shortcomings of Google Calendar.

My advice is don't waste too much time on Google Calendar or Tasks.  Unless someone knows they have resolved the issues.